# Deleting a row past Today's date and a column value is blank - Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am working on a schedule and it has 42 potential loading times during each day. Not all loading times will be used, I am looking to delete the unused rows. I would like the rows to be deleted if it is past today's date and if column F is blank. I do not want to just delete all rows past today's date as some information may be filled out later on before archiving is initiated. I was unable to get a script to come close to this so I do not have an example to post.

Google Sheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aI2uY_i-cwEfCm6RnsQP1_7XUojMBdTM6EFpCRmvlpc/edit#gid=1905407532

Bonus, if there is a way to auto populate the schedule with the date and appointment columns based on the pattern (42 of each date in column D, 3 appointments for each of the 14 time slots on each date in Column E, and column P having 1 2 or 3 for each time slot) in the sheet that would save me a lot of time as I do that manually right now. The information being automatically populated would have to move with the row to the archive sheet which is an automated process as well.

Archive script

```
function createTrigger()
{
    ScriptApp.newTrigger("myFunction")
        .timeBased()
        .atHour(1)
        .nearMinute(1)
        .everyDays(1)
        .create();
}

function myFunction()
{
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Schedule'); //source sheet
    var testrange = sheet.getRange('AE:AE'); //range to check
    var testvalue = (testrange.getValues());
    var csh = ss.getSheetByName('Archive'); //destination sheet
    var data = [];
    var j = [];
    //Condition check in H:H; If true copy the same row to data array
    for (i = 0; i < testvalue.length; i++)
    {
        if (testvalue[i] == 'Yes')
        {
            data.push.apply(data, sheet.getRange(i + 1, 1, 1, 31).getValues());
            //Copy matched ROW numbers to j
            j.push(i);
        }
    }
    //Copy data array to destination sheet
    csh.getRange(csh.getLastRow() + 1, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
    //Delete matched rows in the source sheet
    for (i = 0; i < j.length; i++)
    {
        var k = j[i] + 1;
        sheet.deleteRow(k);
        //Alter j to account for deleted rows
        if (!(i == j.length - 1))
        {
            j[i + 1] = j[i + 1] - i - 1;
        }
    }
}

function deleteTrigger()
{
    ScriptApp.deleteTrigger("myFunction");
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems that the Spreadsheet cannot be opened. And, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. What is `Bonus`? Are there 2 questions in your question?

Comment: Please make the spreadsheet available for edit by anyone, so that the community can use it. And before doing so, take care to remove sensitive information.

Comment: Should be open to edits now

Comment: Have you gotten any further with this?

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't made any progress, not from a lack of trying (read: googling lol)

Comment: Can you explain what "loading time" is and how there are "42" possible of those.?

Comment: So a loading time is a set time (ex 8:15) in which a truck can be loaded in the yard, like an appointment. We have 3 loading crews and 14 set times we will schedule loading, so 42 total. The issue I have is we never use all 42 load times but the employees who schedule the trucks to be loaded want to see all 42 loading time slots so they can easily schedule a truck. But at the end of they day I want the blank lines to be deleted for that day, and if a certain column has a value I want that row to archive. The reason everything cant archive at the end of the day is if a row still requires info.

Comment: Have you tried sorting, then selecting all sheet data? leaving the empty rows at the bottom? Then apply sort again in destination.